# How to pass the new wp menu item as variable?

Tags: php, wordpress

I use this WP filter to add a new item to my menu location "main-menu".

```
    $logo = 'my logo';
    function new_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {
        if($args->theme_location == 'main-menu') {
            $new_item = '<li class="spec"><a href="#"> $logo </a></li>';
            $items = $new_item.$items;
        }
        return $items;
    }
    add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items', 10, 2);

    wp_nav_menu(
    array(
        'theme_location' => 'main-menu',
        'depth' => '3',
        'link_before' => '<span>',
        'link_after' => '</span>',
        'echo' => true ,
        'items_wrap' => '<ul class="%2$s clearfix">%3$s</ul>',
    )
);
```

The problem is that the filter return the main-menu with the new item but with empty value. he didn't output the item value (my logo) if passed as variable.

Comment: `$logo` should be replaced if you use double quotes (`"`) for the surrounding string.

Answer (score 0):

I solve it by passing my value with function

```
function my_logo() {
    $logo = 'my logo';
    return $logo;  
}

function new_nav_menu_items($items, $args) {
if($args->theme_location == 'main-menu') {
    $new_item = '<li class="spec"><a href="#"> my_logo() </a></li>';
    $items = $new_item.$items;
}
return $items;
}
add_filter('wp_nav_menu_items', 'new_nav_menu_items', 10, 2);
```